# I want to make a schedule of my opening hours in 2 shifts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript can anyone help me please?
for some reason it won't work. either it won't open or it won't close.
I would like to create a schedule that indicates that we are open in the morning and closed during the lunch break and then open again in the afternoon and close again at the end of the working day. I would also like to indicate: we open within x minutes and close within x number of minutes.

you can also go to https://codepen.io/Wolf91/pen/KKNjzGg
to eddit the code there.
this is what I have:

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var weekday = [];
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

var currentDay = weekday[currentDate.getDay()];

var currentTimeHours = currentDate.getHours();
currentTimeHours = currentTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + currentTimeHours : currentTimeHours;
var currentTimeMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var timeNow = currentTimeHours + "" + currentTimeMinutes;

var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //this works at hightlighting today

var openTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.opens').text().split(":");

var openTimeHours = openTimeSplit[0];
openTimeHours = openTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + openTimeHours : openTimeHours;

var openTimeMinutes = openTimeSplit[1];
var openTimex = openTimeSplit[0] + openTimeSplit[1];

var closeTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.closes').text().split(":");

var closeTimeHours = closeTimeSplit[0];
closeTimeHours = closeTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + closeTimeHours : closeTimeHours;

var closeTimeMinutes = closeTimeSplit[1];
var closeTimex = closeTimeSplit[0] + closeTimeSplit[1];

if (timeNow <= openTimex && timeNow >= closeTimex) {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("open");
} else {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("closed");
} 

if (timeNow <= openTimex && timeNow >= closeTimex) {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("open");
} else {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("closed");
} 

/* reopens in the afternoon */
var openReTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.reopens').text().split(":");

var openTimeHours = openReTimeSplit[0];
openTimeHours = openTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + openTimeHours : openTimeHours;

var openTimeMinutes = openReTimeSplit[1];
var openTimey = openReTimeSplit[0] + openReTimeSplit[1];

var closeReTimeSplit = $(currentDayID).children('.recloses').text().split(":");

var closeTimeHours = closeReTimeSplit[0];
closeTimeHours = closeTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + closeTimeHours : closeTimeHours;

var closeTimeMinutes = closeTimeSplit[1];
var closeTimey = closeReTimeSplit[0] + closeReTimeSplit[1];

if (timeNow >= openTimey && timeNow <= closeTimey) {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("open");
} else {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("closed");
}
```

```css
.openinghours {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.today {
    background-color: #489E92;
}

.opening-hours-table tr td:first-child {
    font-weight: 600;
}

td {
    width: 1%;
}

#open-status {
    display: block;
}

.openorclosed:after {
    content:" open during these hours:";
}

.open {
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.open:after {
    content: " open.";
    color: #6C0;
}

.closed:after {
    content: " closed.";
    color: red;
}

/* Layout */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script|Open+Sans');

body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #E8DDB5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;
}

.openinghourscontent {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="openinghours">
    <div class="openinghourscontent section">
        <div class="header">
             <h1>Opening hours</h1>
                        <span id="open-status"><p class="openorclosed">We are currently</p></span>
        </div>
        <table class="opening-hours-table">
            <tr id="Monday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Monday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Monday</td>
<td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tuesday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Tuesday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Wednesday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Wednesday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                   
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens"></td>
                                   
                                    <td class="recloses"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Thursday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Thursday at 9am to 8pm">
                <td>Thursday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Friday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Friday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Friday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                  
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                 
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Saturday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Saturday at 10am to 6pm">
                <td>Saturday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                   
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="opens"></td>
                                    
                                    <td class="closes"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Sunday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Sunday at 11am to 4pm">
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td class="opens"></td>
                
                <td class="closes"></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi wolf and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [guidelines for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please remove the `<script>` element in the HTML section, or explain why downloading a module loader (?) is needed within a Stack Overflow question. To help getting answered, try cutting the code down so it can be tested by readers without waiting to 10 minutes to 9 on Monday to see what happens :)

Comment: Hello @traktor i have deleted the <script> element in the HTML i have added also a link to codepen where you can see it live and eddit.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is the duplication of

```
if (timeNow <= openTimex && timeNow >= closeTimex) {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("open");
} else {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("closed");
}
```

when checking opening times in the morning. Executing this twice  reverses the effect of the first execution:  the presence of `open` or `close` in the class name list would not change.

A second problem is that similar code is executed (without duplication) for afternoon opening times:

```
if (timeNow >= openTimey && timeNow <= closeTimey) {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("open");
} else {
    $(".openorclosed").toggleClass("closed");
}
```

This sets "open" or "close" according to afternoon opening times, *overwriting* an "open" status set for morning opening.

To fix both problems, try removing existing code that toggles classes in two places and calculate a single boolean for "currently open".  Then set the open or closed status:

```
// caculate x and y times...

var bOpen = (timeNow >= openTimex && timeNow < closeTimex)
         || (timeNow >= openTimey && timeNow < closeTimey);
$(".openorclosed").attr("class",
      bOpen ? "openorclosed open" : "openorclosed closed"
);
```

This conveniently sets both required classes to avoid having to figure out which classes should be toggled off and on.

---

**Potentially** there are other issues that could be addressed **as needed**: When testing I padded minute values to be two characters wide to avoid thinking about string comparison results between arbitrary time strings. The code is simplified greatly by putting a colon character in the `timeNow` string and using open and close times directly from the table (no need to split things all over the place). So far there is no code to reset current day highlighting, and the open/closed status is calculated using the time zone of the device used to view the page.

The updated snippet, with test code and some simplifications follows:

```js
"use strict";
// callable test code:
const codeTest = testDate=> {

  var currentDate = testDate; // for testing
  var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

  // current day of week
  var currentDay = weekday[currentDate.getDay()];
  var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
  $(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //this works at highlighting today
 
  // current time
  var currentTimeHours = currentDate.getHours();
  currentTimeHours = currentTimeHours < 10 ? "0" + currentTimeHours : currentTimeHours;
  var currentTimeMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
  currentTimeMinutes = currentTimeMinutes < 10 ? "0" + currentTimeMinutes:currentTimeMinutes;
  var timeNow = currentTimeHours + ":" + currentTimeMinutes;  //! with colon

  console.log("testing %s times for time of day set to ", currentDay, timeNow)
  
  // open times
  var openTimex = $(currentDayID).children('.opens').text();
  var closeTimex = $(currentDayID).children('.closes').text();
  console.log("openTimex %s, closeTimey %s", openTimex, closeTimex);
  
  /* reopen times */
  var openTimey = $(currentDayID).children('.reopens').text();
  var closeTimey = $(currentDayID).children('.recloses').text();
  
  // set currently open status
  var bOpen = (timeNow >= openTimex && timeNow < closeTimex)
               || (timeNow >= openTimey && timeNow < closeTimey);
  $(".openorclosed").attr("class",
      bOpen ? "openorclosed open" : "openorclosed closed"
  );
};

// click handler to test code:
const test = event => {
   console.clear();
   codeTest(new Date(
     document.getElementById("date").value + 'T' 
     + document.getElementById("time").value
   ))
};
```

```css
.openinghours {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.today {
    background-color: #489E92;
}

.opening-hours-table tr td:first-child {
    font-weight: 600;
}

td {
    width: 1%;
}

#open-status {
    display: block;
}

.openorclosed:after {
    content:" open during these hours:";
}

.open {
    color:green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.open:after {
    content: " open.";
    color: #6C0;
}

.closed:after {
    content: " closed.";
    color: red;
}

body {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #E8DDB5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;
}

.openinghourscontent {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Date <input id="date" type="date" value="2021-03-22"></label> and 
<label>time <input id="time" type="time" value="08:00"></label>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button>
<hr> <!-- end of test button HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <section class="openinghours">
    <div class="openinghourscontent section">
        <div class="header">
             <h1>Opening hours</h1>
                        <span id="open-status"><p class="openorclosed">We are currently</p></span>
        </div>
        <table class="opening-hours-table">
            <tr id="Monday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Monday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Monday</td>
<td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tuesday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Tuesday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Wednesday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Wednesday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Wednesday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                   
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens"></td>
                                   
                                    <td class="recloses"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Thursday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Thursday at 9am to 8pm">
                <td>Thursday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                    
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Friday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Friday at 9am to 6pm">
                <td>Friday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                  
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="reopens">14:00</td>
                                 
                                    <td class="recloses">18:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Saturday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Saturday at 10am to 6pm">
                <td>Saturday</td>
                <td class="opens">09:00</td>
                                   
                                    <td class="closes">12:00</td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td class="opens"></td>
                                    
                                    <td class="closes"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Sunday" itemprop="openingHours" title="Open Sunday at 11am to 4pm">
                <td>Sunday</td>
                <td class="opens"></td>
                
                <td class="closes"></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

---

I haven't looked at updating the "open/closed" status using an interval timer. That's quite an upgrade to the posted code and  I would  suggest considering rewriting the page to generate the opening hours table from data held in JavaScript (possibly loaded from a `.json` file) rather than putting the data in the HTML.